# How do I get data from two HTML Divs using preg_match?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to get data between this two div:

```
--<div id="p_tab4" class="p_desc" style="display: block;">
--<div id="p_top_cats" class="p_top_cats">
```

I am using the below regex, but it's not getting me anything:

```
/<div id=\"p_tab4\" class=\"p_desc\" style=\"display: block;\">(.*?)<div id=\"p_top_cats\" class=\"p_top_cats\">/
```

How can I correct this regex?

Comment: if you have php5 use DOMDocument http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php ..

Comment: Using regex to get data out of even a well formed HTML document is going to be a pain - treat it as what it is - a DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems nothing wrong with your regex but you need to turn on the DOTALL mode `s`, so that the dot in your regex will also matches the newline character (*line breaks*).

```
~<div id=\"p_tab4\" class=\"p_desc\" style=\"display: block;\">(.*?)<div id=\"p_top_cats\" class=\"p_top_cats\">~s
```

Code:

```
$re = '~<div id=\"p_tab4\" class=\"p_desc\" style=\"display: block;\">(.*?)<div id=\"p_top_cats\" class=\"p_top_cats\">~s';
$str = "--<div id=\"p_tab4\" class=\"p_desc\" style=\"display: block;\">\n--<div id=\"p_top_cats\" class=\"p_top_cats\">";
preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hJ7eW8/1)

Comment: Hi @Avinash please tell me how do i achieve it using preg_match() in php because I not expert in regx. I tried         preg_match('/<div id=\\"p_tab4\\" class=\\"p_desc\\" style=\\"display: block;\\">(.*?)<div id=\\"p_top_cats\\" class=\\"p_top_cats\\">/', $str)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your HTML is somewhat well formed, like below:

```
<div id="p_tab4" class="p_desc" style="display: block;">...</div>
some stuff in between
<div id="p_top_cats" class="p_top_cats">
</div>
```

You can make use of DOMDocument and XPath:

```
$html = <<<'EOS'
<div id="p_tab4" class="p_desc" style="display: block;">
some stuff in between
<div id="p_top_cats" class="p_top_cats">
</div>
</div>
EOS;

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$query = '//node()[preceding-sibling::div[@id="p_tab4"] and following-sibling::div[@id="p_top_cats"]]';

foreach ($xpath->query($query) as $node) {
    echo $node->textContent, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: it's like this  @Jack <div id="p_tab4" class="p_desc" style="display: block;">
some stuff in between</div>some stuff in between
<div id="p_top_cats" class="p_top_cats">some stuff in between
</div>

Comment: @Keyur I've updated my answer to select nodes in between the two siblings.